# Codeigniter: Check csv file and compare with a string

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a csv file, that contains a lot of information like:

> FiscalCode, Number, Data

I have a fiscalCode of a person, and I should compare if the fiscalCode of person is in the csv file.

How can I do??

I have think something like:

```
$filename = ('mycsvfile.csv');


            $f = fopen($filename, 'r');
            if ( $f ) {
                while( ( $line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false){
                     // there i should compare
                }
            }
```

Comment: It could help.. but My question is also how can compare with for example $FiscalCode ( the fiscal code of the person that i have)

Comment: it's in the second highest voted answer: `str_getcsv()`